# VBA code help - Button changing wording and colour

Tags: excel

I want to create a "button" in excel and want to assign VBA or macro code please.

I want initially burgendy color of button saying "unchecked" and when clicked it should say "checked" and change color to Green (from red or burgendy)

upon clicking again it should go back to unchecked and colour should be burgendy

Can someone please help.

Thanks in anticipaiton

Kind regards,

Azid

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following. On your excel worksheet, create a shape. Go to Insert/Illustrations/Shapes/ and then choose a rectangular shape. It will come up as blue. You can change by editing to your required default colour manually to set it up.

On the top left hand corner, you should change the name of the the shape, so that you can call/reference it in your VBA code, for example "**Button1**".

You could add/edit text in that Shape. For example "unchecked" as the default text.

Then right click on the shape and Assign Macro. You can then link to you Sub procedure in the VBA, which will get called whenever it is clicked.

In your VBA code editor, you could then add the following code:

Sub ButtonClick()

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button1")).Select

If (ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "unchecked") Then

    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 200, 255)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "checked"
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Checked"
ElseIf (ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "checked") Then

    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(200, 255, 255)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "unchecked"
    Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "UnChecked"

End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Button1_Click() 
    Dim Sh As Shape
    Dim innerText As String
    Set Sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    innerText = Sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.TrimText.text
    
    If (StrComp(innerText, "Unchecked", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        Sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 200, 255)
        Sh.Fill.Transparency = 0
        
        Sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.text = "Checked"
    ElseIf (StrComp(innerText, "Checked", vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
        Sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(200, 255, 255)
        Sh.Fill.Transparency = 0
        Sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.text = "Unchecked"
    End If
End Sub
```